# Error in matlab socket

Tags: android, matlab, sockets

I have a script in Matlab that communicates with two android smartphones. Here is the relevant part of the code:

```
% wait for a client
t = tcpip('0.0.0.0',8080,'NetworkRole','server');

%set read buffer
set(t,'InputBufferSize',6000);
set(t,'Timeout',3);

% open the socket
fopen(t);

%read the bytes
file=fread(t,6000,'uint8');

%do something with the file
[a,~]=find(file);
file((a(end))+1:end)=[]; %here is the problem

%close the socket
fclose(t);
```

Sometimes when a client connects, the script returns an error:
`Subscripts indices must either be real positive integer or logicals.`

I am not sure whether this is a network error or whether there are some errors in how I have written the code?

Comment: To which line of this code does the error refers ?

Comment: I've just edited the code.

Comment: ok, what is `a` ? Your problem comes from here.

Comment: The code fails when you receive nothing or only zeros. Could you explain what the code is supposed to do? Delete tailing zeros?

Comment: Yes, it deletes the zeros in tail. It receives an audio file that is sent from an android device. Then it performs some operations on this audio file.